# How to I create a Dock menu for my AppleScript application?

Tags: macos, applescript, dock, menu-bar, cocoa

I just created an application with AppleScript, and I would like to create custom menu items for its Dock menu, as shown in the image below. How do I do that?

I'm somewhat familiar with AppleScript, so it would be nice if someone could show me how to add a menu item that triggers an applescript

[image: Dock Menu]

Comment: Basic _vanilla_ **AppleScript** lacks the ability to add a custom menu to an application's Dock menu.

Comment: Yes, I assumed AppleScript doesn't have that ability. However, I presume you can run applescript from inside another application, like XCode, which, I presume, does allow you to add items to the dock menu. This is similar to how you can run AppleScript from within terminal or Automator. Does anyone know what application I do have to use to add items to the dock menu @user3439894 ?

Comment: No, I want items to show up in the **DOCK** menu when I right-click on an application (as shown in the image), **NOT** the menubar. Also, I already have the script menu enabled in the menu bar. Thanks for trying to help, though. @user3439894

Comment: You will need to use Xcode to create an app that does what you're looking to do then and this probably falls under software development and is out of scope for Ask Different but can be asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Oh shit, my bad. You're right; I should have phrased that differently. I typed that response to hastily @user3439894

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43421454/macos-add-commands-to-existing-application-right-click-menu-in-dock